# Reflecting actionscript objects

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to reflect an object in actionscript and get the property names back in the order they are positioned in the class?
I have tried the following

```
var reflectionObject : Object = ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(obj);   
var propsArray : Array = reflectionObject.properties;
(orders alphabetically)

var typeInfo:XML = describeType(obj)
(Not sure what order this is)
```

Comment: I have marked Christopher's answer as correct as it helped. The actual answer though is that you can't currently do it in as3. Perhaps as4?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little ways of reflecting an object in AS3, but all of them are mentioned on this [site](http://www.insideria.com/2009/09/as3-reflection-using-describet.html).

Both of your ways are correct.

Other ways of doing so include, but are not limited the following, according to [insideria](http://www.insideria.com/2009/09/as3-reflection-using-describet.html):

---

- **Accessors (Getters/Setters)**

  ```
  var accessors:XMLList = classAsXML.accessor;
  trace("accessors", accessors.length(), accessors);
  ```
- **Properties**

  ```
  var variables:XMLList = classAsXML.variable;
  trace("variables", variables.length(), variables);
  ```

---

**EDIT:** I have revised my answer and I have found the following [site](http://www.negush.net/blog/listing-the-properties-of-an-object/) that adds up some details about reflection.

**EDIT 2:** I knew I forgot something here. What [jonathanasdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314081/jonathanasdf) said in his comment is true: there is no way to get the properties in the order defined in a said class.

Comment: however, you are not going to get them back exactly in the order they were defined in the class. There is no way of doing that, afaik. And there is the .method property too.

Comment: Thanks. I will just have to add some metadata to my classes to achieve this then? I really like using reflection :) thanks